# Is there a Cucumber/Capybara equivalent for BDD/TDD development for C?

Tags: c, cucumber

I am taking an online course that uses Ruby on Rails, and uses Capybara and Cucumber for scenario driven tests.

I have a background in embedded C programming, and was wondering if there is a similar scenario-driven testing framework for C that is in standard use for testing embedded libraries in the industry?

Comment: Look at [cucumber-cpp](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-cpp)

Comment: @AndreyBotalov: Thanks, I'll take a look at that ... after I learn Boost and GTest. Have you seen this in actual use?

Comment: I don't use it. Maybe, [those discussions](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/cukes/cucumber$20cpp$20$7C$20c$2B$2B) will answer this